# Propagator and expectation value

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

Given a propagator of some system, is there a way of finding the expectation value of some operator without knowing the eigenstates involved?

For example, if I have the propagator of a particle in a harmonic potential, and I would like to calculate $\langle\psi|p^2|\psi\rangle$ where $|\psi\rangle$ is the ground state, without actually knowing the ground state.

Comment: If you have the propagator then you know all of the eigenstates of the potential. See L. Brown's book, Quantum Field Theory, first chapter, section 1.5. Armed with this, you can devise a way to this calculation.

Answer (score 1):

**Improved version with respect to the initial one.**

I am not sure about what you actually mean by "propagator". Let us first suppose that you mean $${\cal P}(t_2,t_1):= \langle \psi| U(t_2,t_1) \psi\rangle$$
where $U(t_2,t_1)= e^{-i \frac{t_2-t_1}{\hbar} H}$ is the time evolution operator generated by the Hamiltonian $H$. (I henceforth assume  $\hbar=1$ and I throughout suppose that $H$ does not depend on time.)

If it is the case the answer is that what you can compute is the expectation value of every function of the operator $H$:$$\langle \psi | f(H) \psi\rangle$$
for every sufficiently regular function $f$, since, denoting by $\hat{f}$ the Fourier transform of $f$:
$$f(H) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb R}  \hat{f}(t) e^{it H} dt$$
and thus:
$$\langle \psi | f(H) \psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb R}  \hat{f}(t) \langle \psi | e^{it H}\rangle dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb R}  \hat{f}(t) {\cal P}(-t,0)dt\:.\qquad (1)$$
For instance, as (with my conventions) the Fourier transform of $f(h)=h$ is $\hat{f}(t) = i \sqrt{2\pi}\delta'(t)$, you have:
$$\langle \psi| H \psi\rangle  = i \int_{\mathbb R}  \delta'(t){\cal P}(-t,0)dt$$
Indeed, by direct computation:
$$i \int_{\mathbb R}  \delta'(t){\cal P}(-t,0)dt = -i \int_{\mathbb R}  \delta(t){\cal P}'(-t,0)dt = -i {\cal P}'(0,0) =  -i\langle \psi| \frac{d}{dt}e^{itH}|_{t=0}\psi\rangle =\langle \psi| H \psi\rangle\:.$$

If, instead, by propagator you mean:
$${\cal P}(x_2,t_2, x_1,t_1) := \langle x_2|U(t_2,t_1)|x_1\rangle\:,$$
the same reasoning as above leads to, in place of (1):
$$\langle x_2 | f(H) |x_1 \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb R}  \hat{f}(t) \langle x_2 | e^{it H}|x_1\rangle dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb R}  \hat{f}(t) {\cal P}(x_2,-t,x_1,0)dt\:.$$
Consequently, considering a state $\psi$, for instance the ground state of the harmonic oscillator, we have:
$$\psi(x) = \langle x | \psi \rangle\quad \mbox{and}\quad\overline{\psi(x)} = \overline{\langle x | \psi \rangle}= \langle \psi | x \rangle\:,$$ so
$$\langle \psi | f(H) |\psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R} \hat{f}(t) \langle \psi | x_2\rangle \langle x_2| e^{it H}|x_1\rangle \langle x_1|\psi\rangle dx_2 dx_1 dt$$ $$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb R^3}  \hat{f}(t) \overline{\psi(x_2)}\psi(x_1){\cal P}(x_2,-t,x_1,0)dx_2 dx_1 dt\:.$$
In particular, dealing with as for the computation of $\langle \psi| H \psi\rangle$ above:
$$\langle \psi| H \psi\rangle = -i \int_{\mathbb R^2} \overline{\psi(x_2)}\psi(x_1)\frac{\partial{\cal P}(x_2,-t,x_1,0)}{\partial t}|_{t=0}dx_2 dx_1 $$

Comment: I have trouble following your answer. What do $x_1,x_2$ mean in the definition of $P$ when the right-hand side depends on times $t_1,t_2$? Also, I believe the "propagator" in the question was about the Green function corresponding to some Schr. equation, not to arbitrary function $\psi$.

Comment: Sorry it's just a stupid misprint replace $x$ for $t$ in both slots. I am correcting.

Comment: Concerning your second question. Indeed I **interpreted** the question in that way, since the OP mentioned something like $\langle\psi| p^2  \psi \rangle$. In fact I wrote  
<<I am not sure about what you actually mean by "propagator">>. Maybe, the OP meant $\langle x_2| U(t_2,t_1)|x_1\rangle$, I do not know I hope he/she will clarify better the question. In case I will make more precise my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I meant by propogator was
$\mathcal{P(x_2,t_2;x_1,t_1}) = \langle x_2|U(t_2,t_1)|x_1\rangle$.
But I would like to calculate the expectation value of some operator (which in general is not a function of the hamiltonian) in the ground state, without actually having the ground state. Meaning All I have is the propogator as defined here and no eigenstates of the system.
The question is, is it possible to do this?